# PhoneGap - Change Required App Permissions

Tags: cordova

PhoneGap is great, but once it makes the App for you, there is loads more you need to do manually before it works. One of these things is Required Permissions. I have uploaded the APK to Google Play, and it states I require permissions for camera etc, which I do not and will never do with my app. How do I change these permissions? I was able to do it within Flash when I made an app, but when you use PhoneGap within Dreamweaver it doesn't ask you anything. I had to CMD everything else in, and edit the XML files. A flaw if you ask me.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 3):

You have to open up your AndroidManifest.xml and remove the permissions you don't need from the app. If you look at the docs site each API lists which permission it needs.

At a bare minimum you should always keep these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If you are using PhoneGap Build you need to modify your config.xml to specify what features your app actually uses. Look at:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

for more information.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I built the application with Dreamweaver CS6 and this file does not appear to exist in the files list, only config.xml.

Comment: Edited my answer to point you to the PG build doc.